What is the "idiomatic Zig way" of doing these matrix operations as functions?
By idiomatic, I am referring to the way a Zig programmer would expect them to work. I have the following matrix structure:
pub fn Matrix(comptime T: type) type {
    const _supported = whatSupportedNumericType(T);
    if (_supported == SupportedNumericType.Unsupported) {
        ("Unsupported type");
    }
    return struct {
        const Self = ();

        data: []T,
        rows: usize,
        cols: usize,
        allocator: std.mem.Allocator,

        pub fn init(allocator: std.mem.Allocator, rows: usize, cols: usize) !Self {
            if (rows == 0 or cols == 0) {
                return std.debug.panic("Matrix dimensions must be greater than zero", .{});
            }
            return Self{
                .data = try allocator.alloc(T, rows * cols),
                .rows = rows,
                .cols = cols,
                .allocator = allocator,
            };
        }

        pub fn set(self: *Self, row: usize, col: usize, value: T) void {
            const supported = whatSupportedNumericType(T);
            const index: usize = row * self.cols + col;
            if (supported == SupportedNumericType.Custom) {
                if (self.data[index]) {
                    self.data[index].deinit();
                }
            }
            self.data[index] = value;
        }

        pub fn get(self: *const Self, row: usize, col: usize) T {
            return self.data[row * self.cols + col];
        }
    };
}

There are more functions, but I just put the simple ones so you get an idea. Also, the supported construct is not relevant for my questions.
There are two functions that I want to make (more but they follow the same template) and don't know how a Zig programmer would expect them to work:
Add function
My initial idea (as I had it done in C) was to have something like
pub fn add(allocator: ?std.mem.Allocator, left: *const Self, right: *const Self, out: *Self) !void

where if allocator was null, the function would expect out to be initialized, but if it held an actual allocator, then it would initialize it. Then I began looking at the source code of the standard library and found that Mutable, an arbitrary precision integer, had the add function defined as
pub fn add(r: *Mutable, a: Const, b: Const) void

where Const is a different arbitrary precision integer. So then, would you, as a Zig programmer expect more the function to be defined as follows?
pub fn add(self: *Self, left: Self, right: Self) !void

Another way I found was
pub fn add(allocator: std.mem.Allocator, left: Self, right: Self) !Self

as is done with the Complex type. So, which approach is more "idiomatic" Zig?
Submatrix function
This function would essentially "extract" or "create" a matrix with the desired rows and columns of another matrix, like what A[[1, 4, 2],[3, 1, 1, 5]] would do in MATLAB. So, again, my first idea was to do it as I had it done in C,
pub fn submatrix(allocator: ?std.mem.Allocator, M: *const Self, rows: []const usize, cols: []const usize, out: *Self) !void

following the same criteria for the allocator as the add function. Then I decided to make an
pub fn initSubmatrix(allocator: std.mem.Allocator, src: Self, rows: []const usize, cols: []const usize) !Self

which, as you might expect, initializes a new matrix as the submatrix of src, but I also want the standard submatrix function. So, like with add, how would you expect this function to work, and what order of arguments would you expect?

I have removed the last paragraph, as it seemed to be a different question. You should create a separate post for it.

Does SO support Zig syntax highlighting wise yet?

@BitTickler -- yes: you can use lang-zig with the triple-backtick syntax.
